# Swift: refactor viewController to pass data to another controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning Swift and I'm trying to develop an app for the TI SensorTag 2.

I'm following [this code](https://github.com/capraconsulting/sensortag-ios-swift/tree/master/SwiftSensorTag), but of course I want to change the view controller keeping only the SensorTag class.

My idea is to have an entry view for the sensor connection and then, when the sensor is detected, the app move to a tabbed view where in every tab I have a reading (temperature, gyro, lux etc).

I'm starting with this view controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Title labels
    var titleLabel : UILabel!
    var statusLabel : UILabel!

    // BLE
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    var sensorTagPeripheral : CBPeripheral!

    // Table View
    var sensorTagTableView : UITableView!

    // Sensor Values
    var allSensorLabels : [String] = []
    var allSensorValues : [Double] = []
    var ambientTemperature : Double!
    var objectTemperature : Double!
    var accelerometerX : Double!
    var accelerometerY : Double!
    var accelerometerZ : Double!
    var relativeHumidity : Double!
    var magnetometerX : Double!
    var magnetometerY : Double!
    var magnetometerZ : Double!
    var gyroscopeX : Double!
    var gyroscopeY : Double!
    var gyroscopeZ : Double!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Initialize central manager on load
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

        // Set up title label
        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = "Sensor Tag"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        titleLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.titleLabel.bounds.midY+28)
        self.view.addSubview(titleLabel)

        // Set up status label
        statusLabel = UILabel()
        statusLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        statusLabel.text = "Loading..."
        statusLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)
        statusLabel.sizeToFit()
        //statusLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: (titleLabel.frame.maxY + statusLabel.bounds.height/2) )
        statusLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.titleLabel.frame.maxY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.statusLabel.bounds.height)
        self.view.addSubview(statusLabel)

        // Set up table view
        setupSensorTagTableView()

        // Initialize all sensor values and labels
        allSensorLabels = SensorTag.getSensorLabels()
        for (var i=0; i<allSensorLabels.count; i++) {
            allSensorValues.append(0)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    /******* CBCentralManagerDelegate *******/

    // Check status of BLE hardware
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
            // Scan for peripherals if BLE is turned on
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
            self.statusLabel.text = "Searching for BLE Devices"
        }
        else {
            // Can have different conditions for all states if needed - show generic alert for now
            showAlertWithText(header: "Error", message: "Bluetooth switched off or not initialized")
        }
    }


    // Check out the discovered peripherals to find Sensor Tag
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {

        if SensorTag.sensorTagFound(advertisementData) == true {

            // Update Status Label
            self.statusLabel.text = "Sensor Tag Found"

            // Stop scanning, set as the peripheral to use and establish connection
            self.centralManager.stopScan()
            self.sensorTagPeripheral = peripheral
            self.sensorTagPeripheral.delegate = self
            self.centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
        else {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Sensor Tag NOT Found"
            //showAlertWithText(header: "Warning", message: "SensorTag Not Found")
        }
    }

    // Discover services of the peripheral
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
        self.statusLabel.text = "Discovering peripheral services"
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }


    // If disconnected, start searching again
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, error: NSError!) {
        self.statusLabel.text = "Disconnected"
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }

    /******* CBCentralPeripheralDelegate *******/

    // Check if the service discovered is valid i.e. one of the following:
        // IR Temperature Service
        // Accelerometer Service
        // Humidity Service
        // Magnetometer Service
        // Barometer Service
        // Gyroscope Service
        // (Others are not implemented)
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!) {
        self.statusLabel.text = "Looking at peripheral services"
        for service in peripheral.services {
            let thisService = service as CBService
            if SensorTag.validService(thisService) {
                // Discover characteristics of all valid services
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: thisService)
            }
        }
    }


    // Enable notification and sensor for each characteristic of valid service
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {

        self.statusLabel.text = "Enabling sensors"

        var enableValue = 1
        let enablyBytes = NSData(bytes: &enableValue, length: sizeof(UInt8))

        for charateristic in service.characteristics {
            let thisCharacteristic = charateristic as CBCharacteristic
            if SensorTag.validDataCharacteristic(thisCharacteristic) {
                // Enable Sensor Notification
                self.sensorTagPeripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: thisCharacteristic)
            }
            if SensorTag.validConfigCharacteristic(thisCharacteristic) {
                // Enable Sensor
                self.sensorTagPeripheral.writeValue(enablyBytes, forCharacteristic: thisCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
            }
        }

    }



    // Get data values when they are updated
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: NSError!) {

        self.statusLabel.text = "Connected"

        if characteristic.UUID == IRTemperatureDataUUID {
            self.ambientTemperature = SensorTag.getAmbientTemperature(characteristic.value)
            self.objectTemperature = SensorTag.getObjectTemperature(characteristic.value, ambientTemperature: self.ambientTemperature)
            self.allSensorValues[0] = self.ambientTemperature
            self.allSensorValues[1] = self.objectTemperature
        }
        else if characteristic.UUID == AccelerometerDataUUID {
            let allValues = SensorTag.getAccelerometerData(characteristic.value)
            self.accelerometerX = allValues[0]
            self.accelerometerY = allValues[1]
            self.accelerometerZ = allValues[2]
            self.allSensorValues[2] = self.accelerometerX
            self.allSensorValues[3] = self.accelerometerY
            self.allSensorValues[4] = self.accelerometerZ
        }
        else if characteristic.UUID == HumidityDataUUID {
            self.relativeHumidity = SensorTag.getRelativeHumidity(characteristic.value)
            self.allSensorValues[5] = self.relativeHumidity
        }
        else if characteristic.UUID == MagnetometerDataUUID {
            let allValues = SensorTag.getMagnetometerData(characteristic.value)
            self.magnetometerX = allValues[0]
            self.magnetometerY = allValues[1]
            self.magnetometerZ = allValues[2]
            self.allSensorValues[6] = self.magnetometerX
            self.allSensorValues[7] = self.magnetometerY
            self.allSensorValues[8] = self.magnetometerZ
        }
        else if characteristic.UUID == GyroscopeDataUUID {
            let allValues = SensorTag.getGyroscopeData(characteristic.value)
            self.gyroscopeX = allValues[0]
            self.gyroscopeY = allValues[1]
            self.gyroscopeZ = allValues[2]
            self.allSensorValues[9] = self.gyroscopeX
            self.allSensorValues[10] = self.gyroscopeY
            self.allSensorValues[11] = self.gyroscopeZ
        }
        else if characteristic.UUID == BarometerDataUUID {
            //println("BarometerDataUUID")
        }

        self.sensorTagTableView.reloadData()
    }





    /******* UITableViewDataSource *******/

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allSensorLabels.count
    }


    /******* UITableViewDelegate *******/

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var thisCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sensorTagCell") as SensorTagTableViewCell
        thisCell.sensorNameLabel.text  = allSensorLabels[indexPath.row]

        var valueString = NSString(format: "%.2f", allSensorValues[indexPath.row])
        thisCell.sensorValueLabel.text = valueString

        return thisCell
    }




    /******* Helper *******/

    // Show alert
    func showAlertWithText (header : String = "Warning", message : String) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: header, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // Set up Table View
    func setupSensorTagTableView () {

        self.sensorTagTableView = UITableView()
        self.sensorTagTableView.delegate = self
        self.sensorTagTableView.dataSource = self


        self.sensorTagTableView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.origin.x, y: self.statusLabel.frame.maxY+20, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)

        self.sensorTagTableView.registerClass(SensorTagTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "sensorTagCell")

        self.sensorTagTableView.tableFooterView = UIView() // to hide empty lines after cells
        self.view.addSubview(self.sensorTagTableView)
    }
}
```

How can I pass my sensorTag object to the TabBar controller?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what do you mean by "TI SensorTag 2", does it mean the 2nd generation of TIsensortag ? Sensortag2541 is the 1st generation, while Sensortag2650 is the 2nd generation.

I trust this swift code only works for 2541, and it might be the reason why your code might not work. 
Also please let me know if you can connect with 2650 using any swift code. Thanks.